# Как составить такой вот sql запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli

Вот моя карта ума. На ней видно что поля таблицы Match team_one и team_two обращаются к таблице Team по полю id, т.е. происходит связь. Из название таблиц можно сделать вывод, что таблица Match, это таблица выводящая матчи, а таблица Team соответственно список команд.
[image]

У меня есть такая форма

```
<form action="{{ route('match.store') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::id() }}" class="uk-input" name="user_id">
    </div>

    <!-- foreach -->
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label">Выбор первой команды</label>
        <select name="team_one" class="uk-select">
            @foreach($teams as $team)
            <option value="{{ $team->id }}">{{ $team->id }}. {{ $team->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label">Выбор второй команды</label>
        <select name="team_two" class="uk-select">
            @foreach($teams as $team)
            <option value="{{ $team->id }}">{{ $team->id }}. {{ $team->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label">Сатус матча</label>
        <select name="status" class="uk-select">
            <option value="1">Предстоящий матч</option>
            <option value="2">Текущий матч</option>
            <option value="3">Прошедший матч</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <label for="factor" class="uk-form-label">Factor</label>
        <input id="factor" type="text" class="uk-input" value="Disable" name="factor">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-secondary">Добавить</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Форма добавляет запись в таблицу Match. Теперь возникает вопрос, как же мне вывести данные из таблице Match, напомню, что в этой таблице нет имени команды(таблица Team), а лишь номера этих команд. Мне нужно получить данные из таблице Match, с данными команд, т.е. чтоб к примеру массив team_one содержал данные одной команды, а массив team_two содержал данные второй команды. в одном sql коде, желательно.

Comment: Обычный join по условию `Team.id=Match.team_one OR Team.id=Match.team_two` и у вас на выходе из запроса ровно 2 записи. В каждой строке данные одной из команд. Учитывая, что fetch как раз создает массив вот и получается читаете 2 записи в 2 разных массива и все как вы и хотели. дополнительно можно добавить `order by (Team.id=Match.team_two)` и первая команда в результате будет всегда в первой записи, вторая во второй, не перепутаете

Comment: А на ларавели как такой запрос написать SELECT
    *
FROM
    matches
INNER JOIN teams t ON
    t.id = matches.team_one OR t.id = matches.team_two
ORDER BY
    t.id = matches.team_two

Comment: а для этого надо в вопросе в тегах указывать, что у вас laravel, что бы вопрос смотрел кто нибудь, кто в нем разбирается.

Comment: А как мне их вывести, эти матчи? Нужно чтоб матч выводился в одну строчку, в котором есть ['имя первой команды','картинка 1-ой команды', 'ТЕКСТ','картинка 2-ой команды','имя второй команды'  ]

Comment: ну оформление на экране это уже чисто вопрос верстки. к запросу он явно никакого отношения не имеет. видимо как либо блок, не позволяющий содержимому перезжать на следующие строки при переполнении (как строка <table>) ну и в нем буквально `$arr[0]->name .... $arr[1]->name` (если у вас строки в массиве конечно)